# Can't Figure Out What's Reducing Full Width in Body Section

Tags: wordpress, width

Despite "nomargin" and "nopadding", the body section is being reduced to 980 px. . Any input is much appreciated. Inherited someone else's mess here.

Already updated the theme and from what I've seen in the code, width should be full page.

Live web page is www.aviles-realestate.com
Something in the line below is controlling the width, which is otherwise set to full width.

Despite changing the width manually, width remains restricted in the body section to 980px

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure exactly what part of the site exactly you are talking about but it like you're using bootstrap and your probably might be the "container" class that you are using, if you change these to "container-fluid" you should have full width.